# Как можно спозиционировать данные типы картинок с помощью css?

Tags: html, css

Есть два типа фото, с которыми у меня постоянно проблемы:

1. Когда фото большое `(1920px x 1080px)` , но сам элемент картинки находится в центре и занимает максимум `1170px`, а по бокам уши какого-либо цвета(например, белого). Можно ли как-то с помощью css обрезать эти уши по бокам, что бы `width: 100%;` отрабатывало корректно?

Пример фото для 1го комментария:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Тоже самое с фото, только если активный элемент находится слева. Можно ли как-то дать "фокус" на левую сторону картинки?

Пример фото для 2го комментария:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фото вставляются тегом `img`

Спасибо

Comment: Добавьте код, картинки

Comment: @HamSter добавил картинки

Comment: Нет, на css такое не делается, потому что для него картинка это весь файл, хоть полезного изображения там вообще не будет.

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов Дайте код, Где код?????

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan Да я сюда за кодом пришёл :)

Comment: Можно конечно, вручную обрезай

Comment: Зачем создавать картинки с лишним местом?

Comment: Хочешь чтобы закрыли по причине, что не описана конкретная проблема, а только задание?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

1. завернуть картинку в блок;
2. картинке дать отрицательные боковые отступы, чтобы сместить её в нужную сторону;
3. увеличить ширину картинки, чтобы её хватило на `100%` блока и на добавленные  отступы;
4. блоку дать `overflow: hidden;`, чтобы прятал всё, что высовывается за края.

```css
.crop-both-sides,
.crop-right-side {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.crop-both-sides > img {
  width: 160%;
  margin: 0 -30%;
}
.crop-right-side > img {
  width: 200%;
  margin: 0 -80% 0 -20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="crop-both-sides"><img alt="" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/icsDL.jpg"></div>
<div class="crop-right-side"><img alt="" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEPot.jpg"></div>
```

Еще можно задать картинку фоном и управлять ею с помощью [`background-size`](https://webref.ru/css/background-size) и [`background-position`](https://webref.ru/css/background-position).

Comment: Спасибо, как вариант. Костыльно, наверное, но выход :)